# EventGrid subscription permissions

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-eventgrid

Trying to create an EventGridSubscription using the code from here:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/event-grid-dotnet-publish-consume-events/blob/master/EGManageTopicsAndEventSubscriptions/EGManageTopicsAndEventSubscriptions/Program.cs

however it seems like the ResourceManagementClient needs 'Contributor' permissions, to the subscription, which I really don't want to give to my application.

```
 ResourceManagementClient resourcesClient = new ResourceManagementClient(credential)
        {
            SubscriptionId = SubscriptionId
        };
```

Would think it was enough with 'Contributor' permissions to the ResourceGroup...
Is there a way to create the EventGridPermissions with only 'Contributor' permissions on the ResourceGroup?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to create the EventGridPermissions with only 'Contributor' permissions on the ResourceGroup?

No, it's impossible.

Tightly coupled delivery of the event messages to the subscriber resource based on the [RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal).

At the subscriber (destination) resource, you can add a built-in role assignment such as `EventGrid EventSubscription Contributor` **for Azure AD user**.

Or add co-administrator **at the Azure subscription level**.

Comment: I have "Events" setup when a blob is uploaded to a Storage Account, an EventGrid message is written to a Storage Queue endpoint. There is no `EventGrid EventSubscription Contributor` RBAC role to be found at either 1.) the Storage Account-level, 2.) the EventGrid System Topic-level nor 3.) the Storage Queue-level. Where is this RBAC role granted?