# RBAC Role for writing/editing EventGrid System Topic Subscriptions?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid, azure-queues, azure-rbac

An AD Group needs the appropriate RBAC Role assigned so they can update `advanced filters` on an existing EventGrid Subscription, but I can't find the appropriate Role.

- Source type: `microsoft.storage.storageaccounts`
- Endpoint: StorageQueue
- Use-case: When a blob is uploaded to an Azure Storage Container, an EventGrid message is written to an Azure Storage Queue.

There are a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61525708/eventgrid-subscription-permissions) StackOverflow [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60823873/creating-an-azure-event-grid-topic-error-does-not-have-authorization-to-perfo) that say "Assign an `EventGrid EventSubscription Contributor`..." or the like. This is not an RBAC Role that is found in the Storage Account, Storage Queue nor the EventGrid System Topic.

Any insights on which built-in RBAC Role can be granted in this case? I do not want to create a custom Role if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

To allow Event grid to write messages to the Storage queue, you need to assign Event grid a role on Azure storage queue.

[Storage Queue Data Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal) could fit that goal

And to update Event Grid advanced filters, the AAD group should be assigned the `EventGrid Contributor` and `EventGrid EventSubscription Contrinbutor` [roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authorization#built-in-roles)

Comment: I've tried assigning the AAD Group the `EventGrid Contributor` Role on the EventGrid System Topic. Members of the Group were unable to update EventGrid advanced filters. They received the error: `Deployment has failed with the following error: The client 'xyz' with object id '123' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/write' over scope '/subscription/mySubId/resourceGroups/myRG...' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials`. User refreshed browser, logged out/in of Azure, no change.

Comment: `EventGrid EventSubscription Contributor` is not an assignable RBAC Role in the EventGrid System Topic. I can't find it anywhere, in the Storage Account, Queue, etc. Does the `EventGrid Contributor` Role need to be combined with another Role on the Storage Account? Currently, the AAD Group also has `Reader` and `Storage Queue Data Contributor` on the Storage Account and `Storage Queue Data Contributor` on the Storage Queue itself.